# How to get a timer to end on 0:00 in javascript

Tags: javascript, timer, countdown

I have a timer that counts down from an amount of minutes which a user puts in but now I don't know how to get it to stop once the timer runs out

This is my javascript coding:

```
function getTime(){
    const startingMinutes=prompt("How many minutes is your timer?");
    let time=startingMinutes*60;
    var overMin=0;
    var overSec=00;

    const countdownEl=document.getElementById("countdown");

    setInterval(updateCountdown, 1000);
function updateCountdown(){
    const minutes=Math.floor(time/60);
    let seconds= time % 60;

    seconds=seconds<10 ? '0' + seconds : seconds;

    countdownEl.innerHTML= `${minutes}:${seconds}`;
    time--;

    if (minutes==0 && seconds==00){
        document.getElementById('timesUp').play();
        return;
    }
}
}
```

What this ended up doing was playing the timer sound then the timer went backwards when I was trying to get it to stop.

Comment: @DreamBold What's that supposed to mean? And why not `Date.now()`?

Comment: https://codepen.io/dreambold/pen/KKBNJWN?editors=1011 Just try to use the `clearTimeout()` function to clear your timer, hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

`setInterval()` returns a timer ID. Use that to cancel it later with `clearTimeout()`:

```js
function getTime() {
  const startingMinutes = prompt("How many minutes is your timer?");
  let time = Number(startingMinutes) * 60 + 1;
  const countdownEl = document.getElementById("countdown");
  const timerId = setInterval(updateCountdown, 1000);

  function updateCountdown() {
    time--;
    const minutes = Math.floor(time / 60);
    let seconds = time % 60;
    countdownEl.innerHTML = minutes + ':' + ('0' + seconds).slice(-2);
    if(time <= 0) {
      document.getElementById('timesUp').innerHTML = 'Done!';
      clearTimeout(timerId);
    }
  }
}

getTime();
```

```html
Count down: <span id="countdown"></span>
<div id="timesUp"></div>
```